# Execute a function on "place an order" submit in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is there a Woocommerce before or after "Place an order" (check out) hook so i can execute a function when the user clicks on the "Place an Order" button. I couldn't find the proper hook for this.

Comment: Have you tried `woocommerce_add_to_cart` action hook??

Answer (score 7):

This one will hook you just after the order was create

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_order_processed', 'is_express_delivery',  1, 1  );
function is_express_delivery( $order_id ){

   $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
   //You can do here whatever you want

}
```

Answer (score 3):

`woocommerce_checkout_process` gets executed on clicking submit.